# react navigation v6 and v5, Disable swipe back action

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm working with react navigation 5 :

I created MainStackScreen and AuthStackScreen,

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

function AuthStackScreen() {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Registration" component={Registration} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerNavigator} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="SmsValidation" component={SmsValidation} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="MoreRegistrationInfo" component={MoreRegistrationInfo} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

MainStackScreen :

```
const MainScreen = createStackNavigator();

function MainStackScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <MainScreen.Navigator>
      <MainScreen.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
      <MainScreen.Screen name="SmsValidation" component={SmsValidation} />
      <MainScreen.Screen name="MoreRegistrationInfo" component={MoreRegistrationInfo} />
    </MainScreen.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I want to prevent IOS swipe action back between Login my screens

Comment: set getureEnabled to false on any route you want to disable swiping. This might help https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#gestureenabled

Comment: As the answers mention, you should pass `gestureEnabled: false`, but be aware that using nested stacks might require you to do the same with parent Screens/Navigators. It took me a while to understand why the gesture was still working and it was because the gesture was disable in the child stack, but enable in the parent stack and then I was going back to the parent.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can set gestureEnabled to false in a screen like:

```
<AuthStack.Screen
   name="Login"
   component={Login}
   options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
/>
```

Or the whole navigator like:

```
<AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: false}}>
  ...
</AuthStack.Navigator>
```

Comment: You can also tack it onto the whole navigator if you want to apply it to every screen - `<AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ gestureEnabled: false }}>`

Answer (score 4):

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*                                 AUTH STACK                                 */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

function AuthStackScreen() {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{gestureEnabled: false}} />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Registration"
        component={Registration}
        options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerNavigator} options={{gestureEnabled: false}} />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SmsValidation"
        component={SmsValidation}
        options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="MoreRegistrationInfo"
        component={MoreRegistrationInfo}
        options={{gestureEnabled: false}}
      />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `beforeRemove` listener to prevent going back.
[React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is already just for navigation v6 relevant, but `swipeEnabled` worked for me.

```
<AuthStack.Screen
  name="Login"
  component={Login}
  options={{swipeEnabled: false}}
/>
```